# Utf8 and latin1

Tags: mysql, utf-8

Half of the tables in a database which has alot of data are set to Latin 1.
Within these Latin 1 tables most rows are set to utf8 if the row is expecting text input (anything not a integer).

Everything is in English .

How bad is my situation if I need to convert these Latin 1 tables to utf8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a clarification:  You said "most **rows** are set to utf8"; I assume you meant "most **columns** are set to utf8"?

The meaning of the `latin1` on the *table* is just a default.  It has no impact on performance, etc.

The only "harm" occurs if you do `ALTER TABLE .. ADD COLUMN ..` without specifying `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

You say that all the text is English?  Then there is no encoding difference between latin1 and utf8.  Problems can occur when you have accented letters, etc.

There is one performance issue:  If you `JOIN` two tables together on a `VARCHAR` column, but the `CHARACTER SET` or `COLLATION` differs for that column in the two tables, it will be slower than if those settings are the same.  (It does not sound like you have this problem.)  Again, note that the table's default is not relevant, only the column settings themselves.

Yes, it would be 'cleaner' to have the table default set to utf8.  This should be a way to do it without dumping, but by changing the tables one at a time:

```
ALTER TABLE t CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

That will change the table default *and* any columns that are not already utf8.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump --add-drop-table database_to_correct | replace CHARSET=latin1 CHARSET=utf8 | iconv -f latin1 -t utf8 | mysql database_to_correct

Comment: Hi Praveen , I'm more hoping to find out if the data in my tables will be effected by the change of collation rather than how to perform the action.